# How to restrict file-type in Standard page Attach

Tags: configuration, upload, standardlayout

I'm using out of the box functionality and I'm wondering is there a way to restrict file-type when the user is uploading an image? I like the following file-type to be allowed to upload `png, jpg, gif`, if the user select other than the allowed file-type either gives the message or ignore.

Comment: downvoters: care to explain why you think you should down vote?

Comment: I upvoted this as I think it's a good and perfectly valid question - no idea why this was downvoted twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I able to solve the above issue:

```
public static final List<string> CONTENT_TYPES = new string[]{'image/gif','image/png','image/jpg'};

for(attachment a: Trigger.new)
{
   if (!isAllowedContentType(a.ContentType)) {
       a.addError('only allowed jpg, gif, png files');
   }    
}
```

Private helper method:

```
   private static boolean isAllowedContentType(string selCT)
   {
      for(String ct : CONTENT_TYPES) 
      {
          if(ct == selCT) {
            return true;
          }
      } 
      return false; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

One could create a trigger on the attachment object.  Then check and see if specified name / content match your criteria.  if so do an addError on the object.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm?search_text=attachment